# split data into chunks whilst respecting groups and threshold

Tags: r

Let us say I have data like this:

```
haves <- data.frame(
        indicator = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
    )
```

The indicator defines a group of a row and the rows are sorted by the indicator. The counts of rows for each group are as follows:

```
sum_stats <- haves %>% group_by(indicator) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% ungroup()
sum_stats
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  indicator     n
      <dbl> <int>
1         1     2
2         2     3
3         3     8
```

Let us say we have a threshold of 5 and I would like to combine consecutive groups as long as the total number of rows is not breaching the threshold. Groups should also never be broken up. So the wants for this simplified example are:

```
wants <- data.frame(
        indicator = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
        , group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
    )
wants
   indicator group
1          1     1
2          1     1
3          2     1
4          2     1
5          2     1
6          3     2
7          3     2
8          3     2
9          3     2
10         3     2
11         3     2
12         3     2
13         3     2
```

Is this possible? Any input would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you **don't** want to do this iteratively with loops...right?  You want a more efficient/elegant solution?

Comment: Thanks - I try loops right now. I am sure I get it to work but loops are mostly not liked in the R world - thought some expert may have a solution at their finger tip (-:

Comment: After `summarise(n = n())`, perhaps `cumsum(c(start, diff(cumsum(n) %% threshold)) > 0)`, where a `start` of `1` specifies where the numbering should start, and `threshold` is `5`?

Comment: I think I have it.  I'll post it in a sec.

Comment: that's a brilliant idea. just trying this.

Comment: A word of caution: I suspect one must first `ungroup()` before performing this operation, or all those `cumsum()`s will be calculated *within* each group, rather than over the entire `n` column.

Comment: yep i use ungroup ...

Comment: I just realized that my "solution" might be cripplingly dependent on the coincidental configuration of the data here (specifically the particular distribution of group sizes in this particular example), so I have deleted it until I have either accounted for all distributions of group size or debunked my own attempt.

Comment: @cs0815, what'd be your expected out if first 2 counts sum up to 4 and next one is 8 say?  I mean your threshold value is 5 or more OR upto max 5 only?

Comment: @AnilGoyal For clarity, let us refer to a group generated with `group_by()` as a **"group"**, and let us refer to the `group` number in `wants` as a **partition**.  As soon as the size of the current group causes the current partition to overflow, we create a new partition for that group.  Then we try to add the next groups to this same partition, and so forth.  So the threshold is the constraint `<= 5`, and if a group is singlehandedly larger than the threshold, it gets a partition to itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might help you as I tried it on an extended data sample. Here are some notes on this solution:

- I decided to use `accumulate2` as we would like to see whether the sum of a vector with its previous value (lag value) is greater than 5
- So the first vector would be `n` without the last element and the second would be again `n` without the first element
- Here I also created a `tibble`, putting my new var `grp` into it on setting the first value of `grp` as `1` per first grouping value
- It should be noted that while `.init` is supplied `.x` and `.y` (first and second vector) could be of the same length, otherwise the second one `.y` should be one shorter
- Since `accumulate2` takes a three-argument function for better differentiating of variables I used `..1`, `..2` & `..3` as `..1` is the accumulated value starting from `.init`, `..2` the next value in sequence of first vector `n[-nrow(.)]` and `..3` the next value in sequence of the second vector `n[-1]`
- Since `..1` is the accumulated/ previous value of `grp`, in case the sum of `..2` and `..3` is greater that `5` it remains as is, otherwise it will be added by `1`
  For further information you could check this [page](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

haves <- data.frame(
  indicator = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8)
)

haves %>% 
  group_by(indicator) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(output = accumulate2(n[-nrow(.)], n[-1], .init = tibble(grp = 1), 
                           ~ tibble(grp = if(..2 + ..3 <= 5) {
                             ..1$grp
                           } else {
                             ..1$grp + 1
                           }))) %>%
  unnest(output)


# A tibble: 8 x 3
  indicator     n   grp
      <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1         1     2     1
2         2     3     1
3         3     8     2
4         4     2     3
5         5     2     3
6         6     5     4
7         7     1     5
8         8     1     5
```

Comment: You can use `uncount(n)` at the end, just wanted to show you the grouping.

Comment: thanks that's some R mastery - you may have forgotten library(tidyr)? I will check

Comment: That's very kind of you. I'm just a student as there are great minds on stack I'm learning from.Yes you are right,  I edited. Would you please give me a feedback on how it fares on your original data set?

Comment: It works like a charm as far as I can tell - I read about purr it is powerful - need to learn more advanced r - thanks!

Comment: I will add some explanation shortly for you as I myself recently learn who to use `accumulate` family of function. Thanks for asking such challenging, rich question, you made my day :)

Comment: glad i did - i am just too dim to come up with stuff like this - especially on a friday - you are pretty good for a "slow learner" (-:

Comment: No, you've got quite a reputation which is quite telling how good you have been, but it is all about experience and whether you already solved something similar. It's quite natural when we have less experience is some areas and more in others.

Comment: @cs0815 I added some notes to further clarify the solution. In case there was anything I could explain more, please just let me know.

Comment: Just FYI: I realized that my own "solution" might be cripplingly dependent on the coincidental configuration of the data here (specifically the particular distribution of group sizes in this particular example), so I have deleted it until I have either accounted for all distributions of group size or debunked my own attempt.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much dear Arun, I wouldn't have been able to do this if I didn't weren't for friends like you.

Comment: I remember that you were working on accumulate and this is a very good solution.

Comment: Luck has been by my side lol, yeah Anil has been kind enough to teach me about it and you also were generous as always to answer my questions. I didn't expect `accumulate` to be this useful and applicable on many problems.

Comment: It is only your effort and patience that finally pays off :-)  It takes some time to get into the R groove.  With this kind of solutions, I think you and Anil are officially masters in the field

Comment: Not without your teachings and guidance. This idea of creating a `tibble` is a rare gem. Very interesting and useful.

Comment: @Greg It seems fine to me, but don't abandon it. There must be an easier way than mine as I've been meaning to use `accumulate` but of course there is an easier and maybe more efficient way like yours.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment, but sadly my `consec()` function turned out to be garbage: I debunked it with some basic counterexamples: `consec(2,2,11)`, `consec(1,1)`, and so forth.  As it turns out, it's far more likely to fail than to succeed!

Comment: @akrun Dear Arun I didn't notice the rest of your kind remarks in your last comment then. I am very proud to receive such compliments from someone of your stature as these words encourage me to try even harder from now on since I started from ground zero. Thank you very much and I'm sure Anil will also appreciate your support and generosity.

Answer (score 4):

Dear Ronak has sometimes referred about library `MESS`, where is useful for its function `cumsumbinning` doing exactly as desired.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(MESS)

haves <- data.frame(
  indicator = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
)

haves %>%
  count(indicator) %>%
  mutate(xx = cumsumbinning(n, 5)) %>%
  uncount(n)
#>    indicator xx
#> 1          1  1
#> 2          1  1
#> 3          2  1
#> 4          2  1
#> 5          2  1
#> 6          3  2
#> 7          3  2
#> 8          3  2
#> 9          3  2
#> 10         3  2
#> 11         3  2
#> 12         3  2
#> 13         3  2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>